# Ms Access VB6 update recordset instead of duplication

Tags: ms-access, vb6

Hi i am using vb6 ms access backend, instead of updating a record it duplicates and creates a new entry. my table does not use primary key due to the relationship with other tables. How can i make it update a record and not duplicate here is my code

```
Private Sub cmdSave_Click()
With Connect.rsitem
       .Open , , adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
        If EditItem = False Then .AddNew
           !itemno = txtItemNo.Text
           !desc1 = txtDesc1.Text
           !desc2 = txtDesc2.Text
           !onhandqty = txtOnhandQty.Text
           !unitprice = txtUnitPrice.Text
           !Size = txtSize.Text
           !upc = txtupc.Text
           !Ordercost = txtOrderCost.Text
   .Update
   .Close
End sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Do select query first ..

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

rs.Open "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE itemno = '" & txtItemNo.Text & "'"
If Not rs.BOF and Not rs.EOF then

  'save the record ......

End If
If rs.State = adStateOpen Then rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
```

Comment: That's a cool way to do it with a select statement, I've never thought of that!  I always use `rs.findfirst()` and  `if .nomatch`.  I'm not sure if there is a benefit either way though.